# phpdoc suggesting type for $this->someField

Tags: netbeans, phpdoc, phpstorm

In Netbeans and phpStorm,
this works as expected:

```
public function someMethod() {
    $objectA = uberEnterprisyFactory('someclassA');
    /* @var $objectA TheClassA */

    // $objectA-> (autocomplete for TheClassA is displayed, good)
```

This does not:

```
public function someMethod() {
    $this->objectA = uberEnterprisyFactory('somemodelA');
    /* @var $this->objectA TheClassA */

    // $this->objectA-> (no autocomplete here, not good, $this->objectA is inferred to be null)
```

How can I sugest type of `$this->someThing` to Netbeans and/or phpStorm?

Comment: Is 'objectA' a magic property?

Comment: @Nikolay Matveev no magic, simple "private $objectA;" in class definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following PHPDoc annotation:

> class MyClass {
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @var MyPropertyClass
>  */
> private $myProperty
> ```
>
> }