# IDEA PHP type annotation

Tags: types, annotations, intellij-idea, comments

I am using IntelliJ IDEA to develop a PHP project. However, in some functions I get dynamically typed variables, i. e. I do not know beforehand what type they are, for instance when I loop through an array of objects, IDEA does not know what type the objects within have.

My question is: how can I, using comment annotations, tell IDEA which suggestions to show me for that object? That would be pretty handy, thanks in advance! I think it would be something like this:

```
/* @type: $object:MyClassName */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [PHPDoc support](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/features/index.html#PHPDoc_support) and [phpdoc suggesting type for $this->someField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750156/phpdoc-suggesting-type-for-this-somefield).

Comment: Ah, found it. Like using `/* @var ClassType $variable; */`